# theres is a way to change the color map with angular2 google maps

Tags: google-maps, angular

I want to change de color of the map, I'm using angular2-google-maps, I have found https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com where I can change the map style, but how can I do this with angular 2?

Comment: Have you tried applying your style to this: `sebm-google-map-container`?